# Регулярное выражение ставящая двойные ковычки " " полсе слова name: до первой запятой

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такая трока

```
str [{id:100001001,name:Весь МТС Гольфстрим,displayPrice:700,speed_in:1000,channels:223,channels_hd:0},{id:100001002,name:Весь МТС Супер,displayPrice:700,speed_in:500,channels:200,channels_hd:0}]
```

нужно ее привести в такой вид

```
str [{id:100001001,name:"Весь МТС Гольфстрим",displayPrice:700,speed_in:1000,channels:223,channels_hd:0},{id:100001002,name:"Весь МТС Супер",displayPrice:700,speed_in:500,channels:200,channels_hd:0}]
```

Значение для ключа name: обернуть в " " двойные ковычки.

Пробовал так но не получилось
`str = str.replace(/name:(\b\w+\b)/gim, 'name:"$1"')`

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы уверены, что str это строка? По структуре похоже, что это массив объектов

Comment: А какая разница что это? Но судя по всему у ТС проблема именем ключа, поскольку тот с пробелами в названии.

Comment: Да это строка. которая улетает запросом на бэк. На graphql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое и незамысловатое, что напрашивается:

```
console.log( str.replace(/(.*name\:)(.*?)(,.*)/gim, '$1"$2"$3')  );
```

**UPD:**

```
console.log( str.replace(/name\:(.+?),/gim, 'name\:"$1",') );
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но сработало только на втором name 
arrs [{id:100001001,name:Весь МТС Гольфстрим,displayPrice:700,speed_in:1000,channels:223,channels_hd:0},{id:100001002,name:"Весь МТС Супер",displayPrice:700,speed_in:500,channels:200,channels_hd:0}]

Comment: Только что сам заметил, когда попытался оприходовать результат. В принципе можно разбить на большее число переменных по тому же принципу, если не мудрствовать.)  Но можно и по другому. Ща  кофе наверну и додумаю другой способ.)

Comment: Бро, спасибо большое! Я разбил на каждый объект в отдельности. И все заработало.!!!!! 
Ты лучший!!!!!!

Comment: Я уже проUPD-ил свой коммент и сделал кратче и ёмче. Проверьте. Вот что животворящий кофе делает с сонными мозгами.)

Comment: Да, так еще лучше. Сразу по всей сроке делает. Без ограничения по размеру. Большое спасибо!!!